# Is there a function which can return negative ranking for values. Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a scenario where I have to rank negative for values below a threshold limit in SQL. Can anyone help me in this?

```
Name    Target  Rank
John    2500    -2
Hopkins 4000    -1
Paul    5000    0
Gracia  5200    1
```

Above is example fro target table. I need to assign ranks as shown. For people having value 5000 should be assigned a '0'. For resource having below 5000 should have a negative value ranking (-1, -2,-3...) For resource above 5000 should have positive rank value(1,2,3) ranking. – [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtW6X.png)

Comment: Seems like you could split your ranking query into two, ranking the population < 5000 and the population > 5000 separately.

Answer (score 4):

Use a combination of the `ROW_NUMBER()` and `COUNT()` analytic functions:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Name, Target ) As
SELECT 'John',    2500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Hopkins', 4000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Paul',    5000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Gracia',  5200 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT t.*,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY target ASC )
         - COUNT( CASE WHEN target < 5000 THEN 1 END ) OVER ()
         - 1 AS rnk
FROM   table_name t;
```

**Output**:

```
NAME    | TARGET | RNK
:------ | -----: | --:
John    |   2500 |  -2
Hopkins |   4000 |  -1
Paul    |   5000 |   0
Gracia  |   5200 |   1
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d438b187bef8c955814b4252c737b068)*

---

**Update**:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Name, Target ) As
SELECT 'John',    2500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Hopkins', 4000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Bob',     5000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Smith',   5000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Paul',    5100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Janet',   5100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Gracia',  5200 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**: If you want a unique rank per row and do not want a rank 0 row if there is not a value of 5000:

```
SELECT t.*,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY target ASC, name ASC )
         - COUNT( CASE WHEN target < 5000 THEN 1 END ) OVER ()
         - CASE WHEN target > 5000 AND COUNT( CASE WHEN target = 5000 THEN 1 END ) OVER () = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS rnk
FROM   table_name t;
```

**Output**:

```
NAME    | TARGET | RNK
:------ | -----: | --:
John    |   2500 |  -2
Hopkins |   4000 |  -1
Bob     |   5000 |   0
Smith   |   5000 |   1
Janet   |   5100 |   2
Paul    |   5100 |   3
Gracia  |   5200 |   4
```

**Query 2**: If you want rows with the same target to have the same rank and to only have targets of 5000 have a rank of 0:

```
SELECT name,
       target,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY target ASC )
         - COUNT( CASE WHEN target < 5000 AND rn = 1 THEN 1 END ) OVER ()
         - CASE WHEN target > 5000 AND COUNT( CASE WHEN target = 5000 AND rn = 1 THEN 1 END ) OVER () = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS rnk
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY target ORDER BY name ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
);
```

**Output**:

```
NAME    | TARGET | RNK
:------ | -----: | --:
John    |   2500 |  -2
Hopkins |   4000 |  -1
Bob     |   5000 |   0
Smith   |   5000 |   0
Janet   |   5100 |   1
Paul    |   5100 |   1
Gracia  |   5200 |   2
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4119a32aec52c7c4d9a655545aafb14a)*

Comment: This query has some difficulties in case that the table doesn't contain a row with `TARGET=5000`.

Comment: Similary the case with more than one row with `TARGET=5000` should be considered.

Answer (score 2):

This is the worthly transcription of your requirement.

You have three different cases of `target`, so you set up a `case` with three branches calculation the `RANK`.

You may use the normal `RANK` aggregate analytic function, but technically you must `PARTITION BY` on your three cases.

```
select NAME, TARGET,
case when target = 5000 then 0
     when target > 5000 then RANK()
        over (partition by case when target > 5000 then 1 when target < 5000 then -1 else 0 end 
        order by target) 
     when target < 5000 then - RANK() 
        over (partition by case when target > 5000 then 1 when target < 5000 then -1 else 0 end 
        order by - target)
end as rank
from tab;

NAME        TARGET       RANK
------- ---------- ----------
John          2500         -2
Hopkins       4000         -1
Paul          5000          0
Gracia        5200          1
```